# MariaDB master to master replication auto increment is not sequential

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux

I have two master to master MariaDB server replication with the below settings:

```
server A with 192.168.1.100:
------------------------------
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
server-id       = 1
log-bin         = "mysql-bin"
binlog-do-db        = wordpress
replicate-do-db     = wordpress
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
```

and:

```
Server B with 192.168.1.200:
---------------------------------
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
server-id               = 2
log-bin                 = "mysql-bin"
binlog-do-db            = wordpress
replicate-do-db         = wordpress
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 2
```

The replication works great but I have problem with auto increments. As you see they are not sequential. For example:

Server A increments: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and ...

Server B increments: 2, 4, 6, 8 and ...

The problem occurs when I insert 2 records in server A and 1 record in server B, the total primary key of the table will look like this: ID : 1, 3, 4

As you see number two is missing because I have inserted two records in server A. But I need auto increment to generate sequential numbers since we use them as our invoice numbers.  **Gaps can get us in trouble with TAX laws in our country.**

I know this is the internal mechanism for MariaDB and MySQL databases in order to avoid duplicate keys. but I just wanted to know if there is an alternative HA solution for sequential index replication.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` cannot be trusted to avoid gaps in the numbers.  It appears that you *must* avoid them.

Plan A:  Switch to MariaDB and use a `SEQUENCE` table.

Plan B:  Simulate such.

Have a table with 2 columns in one row.  (A second sequence could use a second row, etc.)  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE sequences (
    key CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',  -- the name of the sequence
    invoice_num INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(key)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`key` is needed to uniquely identify the row and lock it (below).

To get the next invoice number:

```
INSERT INTO sequences (key, invoice_num)
        ('a', 1)            -- inserts once; updates the rest of the time
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE invoice_num = LAST_INSERT_ID(VALUES(invoice_num) + 1)
check for errors: that IODKU should retry in Galera, but there still could be an error
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();   -- to get the new value (local to connection)
```

Please test this thoroughly.

That should work even with requests for invoice numbers hitting all Galera nodes "simultaneously".  `autocommit` is sufficient.  That commit is implicit in the IODKU.  It will retry if the commit fails (due to a "simultaneous" hit from another node).

Comment: If it is a simple M-M, designate one Primary to handle the sequences table; make a separate connection to grab a num.  Be ready to procedurally VOID ids that (rarely) get skipped.

Answer (score 1):

All(?) `INSERTs`, including IODKU and `REPLACE` can *burn* ids, leading to gaps.  This happens with the statement is rolled back.  And for `INSERT IGNORE` when some `UNIQUE` triggers "ignore".

Even without multi-master, you can get `AUTO_INCREMENT` values *out of order*.  This is because the auto_inc is grabbed when needed, but not replicated until `COMMITted`.  Replicas will see the ids out of order.

Bottom line:  `AUTO_INCREMENT` guarantees uniqueness, *nothing else*.

(Also, what Gordan says.)

Comment: Thanks and you are right, gaps can also be happened when we delete a row. But as I've mentioned before we use IDs as our invoice numbers and gaps can get us in trouble with TAX laws in our country. So how can I solve this problem?? I can use DRBD solution to replicate database folder and make two servers use one database but like Gordan said, it will affect performance.

Comment: The obvious answer is that you cannot use auto-increment as your invoice numbers. You will need to implement a separate source of uniqueness with full serialisation and prevention of deletions and updating of the ID once inserted using triggers.

Comment: @sajadkamali - I updated your Question to point out the absolute requirement for no gaps, etc.  Then I added another Answer.  (The current answer says that you can't use auto_increment; the new Answer attempts to invent a suitable workaround that should work in Galera; I'm not sure about a simple multi-master configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you need decent performance - no, you can't have sequential IDs. You will have the same side effect with Galera, and different gaps with MySQL Cluster.